# How do you keep your [App/Web].config up to date?

Tags: c#, .net, app-config

With ~5 servers hosting about ~60 instances of the same service, managing my app.config files is a nightmare. There are some items, such as service name, that need to be different, and other items, like assembly bindings that needs to be the same.

Over time they've grown unruly, messy and out of sync; as we just discovered our logs werent working for a few services due to a missing assembly binding.

What do you use to manage them? Is this a case where chef or puppet would be well suited? Is there a tool specifically for .NET that would be better suited?

Comment: One idea is to have a single app.config in some location that is accessable to each project at compile time (such as a shared drive), and when you add it to each project, choose "Add as Link" instead of "Add".

Comment: Our update model doesnt include updates to the config, which as I said before, have to have unique values, such as service name, in order to function properly. Thank you for the comment.

Comment: If you are not recompiling then my suggestion will not work. I would recommend a different approach, such as storing this critical information in SQL server. There you can change it in one place and all instances of your app will read it.

Comment: @NickBailey This question is not appropriate for Programmers. We do not accept questions about how to use tools or tool recommendations. Please do not suggest that people take their questions to other communities, as it often leads to cross-posting. When a question that is not a good fit is cross-posted, it leads to down votes, closure, and deletion (and perhaps even the automatic question blocks). This gives people a poor user experience.

Comment: I'm actually surprised this hasnt been closed yet, but I wanted to see what folks were using.

Comment: What about config transformations? Depending on your usage you may be able to start with a generic config and project specific add/set/delete transformations. However, I only ever used this to manage things like different settings and connection strings between dev/vali/prod environments within a single project.

Comment: @grek40 yea think a bit more ppst production management. Im going to look into Octopus, but may end up doing a custom tool.

Comment: Thank you for the heads up @ThomasOwens.